# Stepper motor resolution

Tags: stepper-motor

What does "mm/step" exactly mean? Where and how is the distance measured? How can it be converted to °/step?
I have been looking for this, but I haven't found the exact answer.

Here is an example datasheet, where the resolution is in this measure given:
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/42855.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The datasheet you cite is for a linear actuator, which is the combination of a stepper motor and a leadscrew. In order to convert from linear to angular measure, you would need to know the thread pitch (how far it moves in one rotation) of the leadscrew.

Comment: Yes +1. One more detail. Lead = thread pitch * starts. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_%28simple_machine%29